# Unable to use geography data type with Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, sqlgeography

I have a problem trying to use SQL Server geography data type with an Azure Cloud Service. I have followed the instructions available at http://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/spatial-applications-in-windows-azure-redux-including-denali, but, when I make a spatial query (in particular, I'm using the STDistance method), I obtain the following message:

> An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
>   (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007000B)","exceptionType":"System.BadImageFormatException","stackTrace":"
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.GLNativeMethods.GeodeticPointDistance(Point
>   p1, Point p2, EllipsoidParameters ep)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.STDistance(SqlGeography other)

I have tried also all the suggestions written in http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazurewebsitespreview/thread/6f68a726-bddb-4312-ae75-043b775da271, but always with no success.

Can anybody help me solving this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post the code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using 32 bit spacial on 64 bit platform or vice versa.

Make sure that the version you are uploading to Azure is 64 bit.